# multiple similar css IDs, simplification?

Tags: css, sass

```
#grid-breadcrumbs-Focus-ST{
  ...
}
#grid-breadcrumbs-F-150-EcoBoost{
  ...
}
#grid-breadcrumbs-Mustang-EcoBoost{
  ...
}
#grid-breadcrumbs-fiesta{
  ...
}
```

All of these are extremely similar differing only in the background image that is projected.  Is there a way to simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you could do something like this:

```
.grid-breadcrumbs{/*common properties here*/}
.grid-breadcrumbs .focus-st{/*different properties for each case here*/}
.grid-breadcrumbs .f-150-EcoBoost{}
.grid-breadcrumbs .Mustang-EcoBoost{}
.grid-breadcrumbs .fiesta{}
```

Your html will be something like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <div class="grid-breadcrumbs focus-st"></div>
    <div class="grid-breadcrumbs fiesta"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would the html look like?

Answer (score 4):

Use attribute start with selector:

```
[id^="grid-breadcrumbs"]{
  /* Represents an element with an attribute name of attr 
    and whose value is prefixed by "value".*/
}
```

More on [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 2):

You can offset all the same attributes into a CSS class.

CSS:

```
.myClass{
    //your css
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
.class{
 #blah
}

#Focus-ST{
  background-image: url("img1.png");
}

#fiesta{
 background-image: url("img2.png");
}
```

and so on.

group all the same attributes in that .class

Answer (score 0):

```
*[id^="grid-breadcrumbs"]{
  /* Your css code goes here */
}
```

1. '*' : This is a wildcard selector that matches any element. It can be used in combination with other selectors to target any element that meets certain criteria.
2. '[]' : This is a attribute selector that matches elements based on the value of an attribute.
3. '^=' : This is a value selector that matches elements where the value of the selected attribute starts with a particular string.

This helped me to achieve multiple ids with same sequence in sass

Comment: It would be nice if you could leave some foot notes for example like explaining what does `[]` do or what does `^=` mean when you're using it in a sass file. This would help not only advanced sass users but also beginners.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).